# Html with embedded svg convert to PDF using Flying saucer Itext batik

Tags: java, itext, batik, flying-saucer

I have a requirement to convert all my html reports to PDF.

Its a nodejs application so i cant find any core module which convert html to pdf.

So I use JAVA FLYING SAUCER JAR to convert html to PDF . **In that every thing working perfectly apart from embedded svg in html** . so i have googling about that i got [this tutorial](http://www.samuelrossille.com/posts/2013-08-13-render-html-with-svg-to-pdf-with-flying-saucer.html)   and [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30083029/how-to-add-svg-image-to-pdf-built-with-html-and-flying-saucer-library-and-batik) . I am a nodejs developer and have basic knowledge about java . i dont know how to integrate this code with flying saucer.

**Please guide me what to do**

.

Below command line is used for convert html to pdf using fying saucer.

```
java -cp flyingsaucer.jar org.xhtmlrenderer.simple.PDFRenderer inpFile.html outFile.pdf
```

I have the source of flying saucer from github

And i use the jar from child project

> flying-saucer-pdf-itext5

use maven to Build and use maven-shade plugin to build a jar with dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolve it with the help of my friend who work in java.

First SVG in my example are generated by highchart api javascript.it is bit complicate svg . so the above tutorial not work for me.So i converted all SVG tag to base64 PNG using svg_todataurl.js.

To generate png base64 in PDF i use the following tutorial.
[base64 encoder](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/using-data-urls-for-embedding-images-in-flying-saucer-generated-pdfs/)

If any help need comment below ..